# Flask accessing config variables when app is created inside of function

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I have the following configuration for my Flask application:

**File Structure:**

```
run.py
app/
  __init__.py
  views/
    main/
      __init__.py
      main.py
  ...
```

**__init__.py**

```
def createpp():
  app = Flask(__name__)
  ...
  return app
```

**main.py**

```
...

key = app.config['KEY']
hashingID = hash(key)

@main.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def main():
  ...
  return render_template('main/main.html')

...
```

As you may see, I want to access `app.config['KEY']` from **main.py**. The issue is, since app is configured inside of `create_app()`, I cannot simply import it.

hashingID is always constant and is used in many different routes, otherwise I would have simply put

```
key = app.config['KEY']
hashingID = hash(key)
```

inside of the route.

Is there a way around this so that I can access config variables from an app instance that is generated inside a function? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you're trying to do.

You can see [in this project](https://github.com/ansible-community/ara/blob/15e2d0133c23b6d07438a553bb8149fadff21547/ara/webapp.py) where we create the `Flask` instance inside a `create_app` function, and then from that same function pass the `app` variable into a number of other functions that perform our various configuration tasks.

The return value of the `create_app` function is ultimately assigned to a top-level `app` variable in the module, which can then be accessed in other modules by importing it as necessary (like [here](https://github.com/ansible-community/ara/blob/15e2d0133c23b6d07438a553bb8149fadff21547/ara/manage.py#L26)).

Comment: Links are broken

Comment: Linked are fixed.

Comment: links are broken again :(

Comment: Links are fixed! Certainly all this maintenance is worth more than -1...